# InstantiationException on Inner Class

Tags: java, exception, inner-classes

I am getting `java.lang.InstantiationException` after running this program, however i was expecting a **Hello World** as a output.

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            new Test().greetWorld();
        }

        private void greetWorld() throws Exception {
            System.out.println(Test2.class.newInstance());
        }

         class Test2 {
            public String toString() {
                return "Hello world";
            }
        }
    }
```

Can some one tell me about this exception and why it is not printing **Hello World**

Answer (score 2):

This is because `Test2` is not a `static` class. Make it `static` to make this work.

```
static class Test2 {
    public String toString() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, move `Test2` out of `Test1`.

Think about how you would normally create an instance of `Test2`. Since it is not static, you can't just do

```
Test1.Test2 obj = new Test1.Test2();
```

You need to be in a non-static context of `Test1`.

That is why you can't directly get the constructor from the `Class` object.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static inner class" in Java!

Comment: @LewBloch What do you mean there is no static inner class?

Comment: I mean that the definition of "inner class" in Java is a nested class that is not `static`, so by definition there's no such thing as a "static inner class" in Java.

Comment: @LewBloch Oh, ok. Edited.

Comment: this works: `System.out.println(new Test2());` without changing Test2 to static.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch It does because you are doing it in a non-static context.